# Crear conexión a base de datos sql en un modulo de drupal 8 MySQL y SQL Server

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal8

Estoy creando un módulo custom de Drupal 8 y quiero incluir una conexión a una base de datos y que devuelva el nombre de las tablas existentes.
El módulo se instala correctamente, aparece en el menú de configuración, **el problema** surge al pinchar en el enlace, pues me dice: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." y no muestra la página. Adjunto código hasta el momento creado.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloController.
 */
namespace Drupal\hello_world\Controller;
class HelloController {
  public function content() {

    $usuario="emerita";
    $password="1234";
    $host="localhost";
    $kk = "";
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO( "mysql:host=$host", $usuario, $password);
        $dbs = $dbh->query( 'SHOW databases' );

        while( ( $db = $dbs->fetchColumn( 0 ) ) !== false ){
        // $kk .= $db."<br>";

        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
       echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => t($db),
    );
  }
}
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Un saludo.

**EDITO**

En vista de que no he podido hacerlo, dado que al tratar con un array no se le puede hacer que muestre $db así, lo que he hecho ha sido crear un formulario y derivar todo a un archivo.php en la propia raiz de Drupal. Después de procesar todo genera un botón para enviar al usuario de vuelta al Drupal base.

No es una forma elegante, y seguramente tenga mas de un problema a nivel de seguridad, pero es una forma que, para salir del paso, sirve.

Al igual este sistema me ha servido para mostrar una serie de imágenes guardadas en la base de datos (están en el sistema de archivo, pero se guarda una "ruta" en la base de datos y el nombre, para poder crear un enlace luego en el src de ).

Igualmente se agradece cualquier apunte al respecto o consejo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la forma mas cómoda, y que me permite hacer lo que quiero, ha sido el siguiente código:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\edicion_slider\Controller\edicionslider.
 */
namespace Drupal\edicion_slider\Controller;
class edicionslider {


 public function content() {


include "llamadabdatossli.php";

    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => basedatosslider(),
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => [
          'edicion_slider/slider_admin',

         ],
      ],
    );
  }
}
?>
```

He montado el módulo de manera normal, pero en el archivo php que va dentro del controller lo que hice fue llamar a una función ubicada en otro archivo, en este caso llamadabdatossli.php. El sistema de Drupal 8 no está mal, pero hay cosas que prefiero gestionar yo de una manera mas directa, pero sin tener que tocar el core. Por tanto la llamada a la base de datos, inserción de imagenes, edición y visualización se hace todo a traves de un archivo, el que mencione antes, que, mediante PDO y prepare statements, gestiona la base de datos y los inputs que el usuario puede hacer. Desde luego, si Drupal 8 te permite hacer lo que quieres hacer, debería hacerse el módulo como indican en los tutoriales, pero en este caso, que quería mas precisión, mas bloques y que un solo bloque puede mostrar mas contenido de manera condicional, está ha sido la mejor manera para mí.